# When does hasEnded() trigger in Android

Tags: android

I want to start animation of another text view after completing an animation.For this i did

```
Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
textView.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
if(animationFadeIn.hasEnded())
{
textView2.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
}
```

But the second animation does not work...Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView2.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

        }

    });
```

you are checking if animation ended which will execute once and as animation has not ended wont trigger

even if you put it in a thread it m8 wrk try this hope it might help and change it according to your need .. i m nt sure but give it a try

Answer (score 1):

`startAnimation()` return immediately, so when you get to `if(animationFadeIn.hasEnded())`, animationFadeIn is still running.

You can use an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29) to know when a given animation ends